# 「ディレクトリ内のファイル名がすべて等しい」の判定をLinuxで行う

Tags: linux, bash

ディレクトリaとbについて、「ディレクトリ内のファイルの名前がすべて等しいか」をLinuxのコマンドで判定するには、どう書けばよいでしょうか。

以下のような場合はtrue、

```
.
├── a
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
└── b
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3
```

以下のような場合はfalseを表示してほしいです。

```
.
├── a
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
└── b
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: この記事が参考になるのでは？ [Diff filenames of two directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/427985) 他にはこんなのも。[Compare the file names in two directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55574994/9014308), [How do I compare file names in two directories in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28205735/9014308)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`diff`コマンドの`-q`オプションを使うことで、ファイルの中身を見ずにファイル名の差分のみ比較できます。
ちなみにサンプルコードの`-r`オプションはサブディレクトリを再帰的に確認するオプションです。

```
MYVAR=`diff -qr a b`
[[ -z "$MYVAR" ]] && echo "合ってます" || echo "違います"
```

参考資料:
[diff to output only the file namesの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6217722)
[How To Bash Shell Find Out If a Variable Is Empty Or Not](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-script-check-if-variable-is-empty/)

Answer (score 2):

`dir1` は以下のようになっています。

```sh
$ tree dir1
dir1
├── a
│   └── 1.txt
├── b
│   └── 2.txt
└── c
    ├── 3.txt
    ├── 4.txt
    └── d
        └── 5.txt

4 directories, 5 files
```

`dir２` は以下のようになっています。

```sh
$ tree dir2
dir2
├── a
│   └── 1.txt
├── b
└── c
    ├── 3.txt
    ├── 5.txt
    └── d
        └── 5.txt

4 directories, 4 files
```

すべての差異を以下のコマンドで確認できます。

```sh
$ diff <(cd dir1; find . -type f | sort) <(cd dir2; find . -type f| sort)
2d1
< ./b/2.txt
4c3
< ./c/4.txt
---
> ./c/5.txt
```

もし差異があるかどうかだけが知りたい場合は `cmp` を使うこともできます。

```sh
$ cmp -s <(cd dir1; find . -type f | sort) <(cd dir2; find . -type f| sort) && echo "差異なし" || echo "差異あり"
差異あり
```

Comment: すでにdiffを使う回答がついていますが、それに比べてこちらの方法にはどういう違いがあるのか(メリット/デメリット)の記載があるとよりよい回答になると思います

Comment: @suzukis たしかにそうですね。アドバイスありがとうございます！